# How can we find number of triangles in a given undirected graph?

Tags: graphs, data-structures

If we assume we have n triangles in a given graph. How can we find the n triangles in O(n) time?

And we also have to add and remove edges in O(log k) when k=|v|

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Please edit the question to add a reference to the original problem. 1) Credit should be attributed. 2) The original problem is probably stated clearer with examples. 3) A reference is apt to motivate people. 4) A reference may save readers who look for related materials lots of time. 4) Many people prefer not to spoil a live coding contest/challenge.